# Oracle VirtualBox; Ethernet No Internet and No Network Access

Tags: windows-10, wifi, virtualbox, bridge

Please Help.I'm using the lastest version of VirtualBox and its extension. I downloaded them yesterday.
I use wi-fi connection, Bridge Adapter with Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter and DHCP Server is enabled.
I want to connect to 192.168.2.5:8080/webui
Before that It worked fine, but My Windows 10 updated automatically and after that my Ethernet shown like this.

Network Connections:
[image: Network Connection]

Virtual Box Adapter:
[image]

Could you tell me What should I input the values of IP Address and IP for default gateway on my Ethernet 2 ?
Please help, I've been googling since 4 days ago but never found the solution.
Thank you and I Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is How I fixed the exact problem by manually updating the virtualbox bridge driver:

1. Update VirtualBox to the Newest version
2. Network and Sharing Center
   Change adapter settings
   Right Click the Main Adapter
   Properties
   Uninstall "VirtualBox NDI56 Bridge Network Driver"
3. Go back to the Properties windows
   Install
   Service
   Have Disk
   Browse
   Now, find the newest driver by: 
   `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\network\netlwf\VBoxNetLwf.inf`

Restart, done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there an issue with version 5.2.0.
Please check https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17186